# I need to install xmllint, but don't know how to

Tags: software-installation

I want to install xmllint, but don't know how. I'm running Ubuntu LTS 20.04.

Comment: If the goal is to LINT some XML, there is the [libxml2-utils](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=xmllint) package, but it’s not often people install this on it’s own. What is the actual issue you are attempting to solve? 

Comment: @matigo it was needed to run a script that i needed to run.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The tool xmllint is part of the libxml2-utils package

As superuser run:-

```
#apt -y install libxml2-utils
```

and the xmllint tool will become available
e.g.

```
xmllint --format your.xml
```